# Why was Chassidus controversial?

Tags: history, chasidut-hasidism, communities

When Chassidus came about, it was very controversial. The Vilna Gaon even put Chassidim in cherem. What were the reasons for the controversy? And why is there peace and mutual respect today between the Chassidim and Misnagdim?

Comment: (Not a complete answer) It was viewed as heresy, for several reasons: 1. The early followers (and some leaders) expressed views that seemed to imply that Talmud Torah - and even Shemirath HaMitzvoth - was not as important as blind faith in HaShem; 2. The blind faith was often manifested as unquestioningly following one Rebbe; 3. The Rebbe was seen as the conduit to serving HaShem; the list goes on. Why is there mutual respect? I'd classify it more as mutual recognition and acceptance of legitimacy assuming certain tenets are followed; flare-ups still occur.

Comment: Somewhat related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/15181

Comment: Craig Feinstein, welcome to Mi Yodeya and thanks for the interesting question. I hope to see you around the site.

Comment: I agree with @SethJ on this - there is not "peace and mutual respect" today but (usually) acceptance.  In broad strokes, Chasidics think that "snags" take the joy out of the religion, and Mitnagdim think that chasidics take the thought out.  Just like any other two marginalized groups, they've formed bonds based on what they have in common as the rest of the world seems to go against them.

Comment: @Charles, Being a "chassidic", I'm rather bothered by your use of the term "snags". It's a rather demeaning term that I, nor any adult Chassid I know, would actually use. Additionally, "peace and mutual respect" is a natural outcome of "acceptance". Of course they still disagree on many things, otherwise they would be the same.

Comment: You make it sound as if Chassidim and Misnagdim can't stand each other, and only tolerate the other's existence because they're on the same sinking ship. That is simply not the case (at least from where I stand), and I would wager that any of the many non-Chassidim here would agree.

Comment: @HodofHod i'm very happy to hear that!  I'm not sure the same can be said in all communities, but it's really wonderful that that sentiment exists. I stand corrected and I apologize. (this is entirely genuine and without irony or judgment)

Comment: @CharlesKoppelman :D The troublemakers are always more vocal, in any group. I'm working on answering your comment below.

Comment: I recently heard in a shiur from Shmuel Braun that talked about a sefer that lists the reasons the Chassidim were put in Cherem.  http://www.torahcafe.com/rabbi-shmuel-braun/collector-of-scattered-souls-video_d300b58a1.html - 7 minutes in he starts talking about a sefer called Shever Posheim from R' Dovid Makover, a student of the GR"A. In that sefer he lists the reasons why the GR"A put Chassidim in Cherem, and some of them are discussed in the Shiur.

Comment: Looks like it's this sefer: http://books.google.co.cr/books/about/%D7%A9%D7%91%D7%A8_%D7%A4%D7%95%D7%A9%D7%A2%D7%99%D7%9D.html?id=VZmAugAACAAJ&redir_esc=y

Comment: A few years ago, I heard in the name of the Nefesh HaChaim that his problem was that they learned musar instead of "normal" learning, and that he couldn't find a full set of Shas in their entire town.

Comment: somewhat related: http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/3821

Answer (score 4):

Depending on who you ask, you may get slightly different answers. This is what I understand, from a mostly historical and Chassidic perspective. (Garnered from R' Yossi Paltiel<sup>1</sup>, Berel Wein<sup>2</sup>, and a bit of Wikipedia<sup>3</sup>.)

The Baal Shem Tov started his teaching not long after the false messiah, Shabtai Tzvi created massive chaos in the Jewish world. Shabtai Tzvi, among many other things, was a kabbalist. The Baal Shem Tov (and the Baal Shems before him) were therefore regarded as *highly* suspicious due to their teaching kabbalah. Many of their kabbalistic practices and beliefs, although more common among Sephardim (since kabbala was always more accepted among Sephardim), were very foreign to Ashkenazim, and considered heretical. Also, even Misnagdic Kabbalists (e.g., the Vilna Gaon), disagreed about different kabbalistic teachings that the Besh"t taught. (Even though, AFAIK, the Baal Shem Tov's teachings all had [strong basis in Lurianic Kabbala](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/8816/883).)

---

Edit: It is very important to note that the above reasons aren't really the things that Misnagdim disagree on with Chassidim. The Misnagdim did, and do, have *ideological* disagreements. The above reasons perhaps can explain why the Misnagdim were so suspicious and rejecting of Chassidus, when they otherwise might have just disagreed with, yet accepted, it. See comments below.

---

The reason for the peace that (B"H) exists now is due to several different reasons.

First, much of the dispute between Chassidim and Misnagdim (at least after the Maggid) existed in Lithuania and White Russia. Ukraine and Poland were already very Chassidic.

The leading dynasty of that region (to my knowledge) was Chabad. The Alter Rebbe did his best to make sure that there was no negative response from his Chassidim to Misnagdic opposition. His son, the Mitteler Rebbe, made the divide even greater. He told his Chassidim to avoid dealing with Misnagdim at all. Don't daven in their shuls, etc. This allowed tempers to cool, and by the end of the Mitteler Rebbe's leadership, much of the old animosity had disappeared.

Then came the ultimate uniting factor: a common enemy. In this case [The Enlightenment movement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haskalah) (*not* to be confused with modern reform, btw). The Enlightenment did their best, through the governments and other means<sup>4</sup>, to forcibly intellectualize Judaism, at the expense of Halacha. The Misnagdim recognized that Chassidism was not what they had thought it was, and the Tzemach Tzedek and R' Itzhele Volozhiner had a close relationship. Together they worked to prevent the government from forcing secular education on orthodox Jewry. (Crucially, this was *not* that they did not want Jews to be educated in secular subjects, but that it should *not* come at the expense of Jewish practice and Jewish education (*Jewish Life and Learning*).)

By this point, the Geonim among the Misnagdim had realized that Chassidus was not heretical, and did not pose a danger as Shabtai Tzvi and Yaakov Frank had, and so the reason for the original disagreement fell away.

---

If you disagree, or have a correction, please do correct me!

---

<sup>1 Who presents (mostly) the Chassidic perspective.</sup> 
<sup>2 Who presents more of a non-Chassidic viewpoint.</sup> 
<sup>3 Who knows?</sup> 
<sup>4: Including masquerading as orthodox schoolteachers in order to educate orthodox children away from orthodoxy.</sup>

Comment: You mean the Misnagdic/Chassidic opposition to his approach? "Der tolk iz un a tolk."

Comment: What exactly was the point of disagreement between the two groups at first?

Comment: @ShmuelBrin [K'Yadua](http://www.sichosinenglish.org/books/making-chassidim/05.htm#n4).

Comment: @Craig, Many things. The Misnagdim didn't like that chassidim placed much emphasis on emotion, specifically joy. They disagreed (at least originally) with the idea of ["tzimtzum aino kipshuto"](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/709/what-is-the-machlokes-between-the-gra-and-baal-hatanya). They were uncomfortable with the idea that Chassidim [elevated the simple, ignorant Jew](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/15181). They didn't like that Chassidim sometimes [followed Kabbala when it conflicted with Halacha](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/15099/883). Etc., etc.

Comment: There is a statement to the effect of "R' Itzhele Volozhiner saw that Chassidim could be Talmidei Chachamim, and the Tzemach Tzedek saw that Misnagdim could be Yirei Shamayim" or something like that.

Comment: @Menachem Yeah, I've heard that in several places; I'm pretty sure Berel Wein repeats it. I have a hard time believing it, though. I simply don't think that either of them were so naive prior to their meeting each other. The fact that they knew each other and got along was probably much more significant to their respective followers than it ever was to themselves.

Comment: @HodofHod: I don't think they themselves said it. I think it was said by others to explain that some of the misconceptions that lead to the schism were publicly refuted.

Comment: @Menachem Oh, I'm sure that they didn't say it themselves, but I think that saying that when they met each other they had some huge revelation is not very likely. Perhaps you can say that their followers learned from their relationship that the "other side" were also righteous people.

Comment: You should clarify tour answer. The Haskalah was not interested in "forcibly intellectualizing" Judaism. If anyone was interested in intervention into the jewish community it was the governments if the interventionist autocratic tutelary state.

Comment: @Jason, the Haskalah was certainly very interested in forcibly secularizing and intellectualizing Judaism. In addition to [working towards](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haskalah#Spread_of_Haskalah_in_Eastern_Europe) this goal [on its own](http://www.sichosinenglish.org/books/branches-of-chassidic-menorah-2/04.htm), it found a willing ally in the [anti-semitic governments](http://chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/109628/jewish/The-Petersburg-Conference.htm) of the time.

Comment: @HodofHod You've got it wrong. I suggest you read Michael Stanislawski, Tsar Nicholas and the Jews.

Comment: @Jason, I'm sure different historians have different opinions on the matter, just as with most everything.

Comment: With the way Chabad chasidut has develpoed in Israel, many here think that those who originally opposed Chasidut had it right the first time.

Comment: @HodofHod I don't think it is correct to say that those who opposed Chasidut, opposed the use of emotion and Joy. These are very important things in the writings of the Rambam for example. What they opposed was the excessive focus on Joy at the expense of halacha. They also feared adherence to a rebbe which do not answer questions with halachic rigor.

Comment: @avi You are correct, of course, hence my use of _"placed_ **much emphasis** _on emotion"_. I would edit to make it clearer and more in line with what you've said if it wasn't a comment.

Answer (score 1):

Hasidism was not 'controversial.' There indeed was a long battle between Hasidism and the Misnagdim (at the level of street battles and burning of books) but the polemic was just as much about miscommunication as an actual Halakhic difference. So 'controversial' is the wrong word.

The Vila Gaon (GR"A) was personally opposed to Hasidism, because he believed them to be heretics. Why did he see them in this way? Because they presented a new and innovative form of religious practice. In particular the new forms of prayer (such as somersaulting) and focus on worldly pleasures. Indeed, the Gaon himself was a Hasid-- he was referred to by his disciples as "Ha-Gaon He-Hasid." But he was a different kind of Hasid, related not to Hasidism as we know it today but the medieval Haside Ashkenaz, who were Mystics but focused on (1) asceticism and (2) elitism. The challenge that Hasidism presented was not a new Kabbalistic belief, but its popularization.

The relationship with Sabbatianism: certainly the belief that Hasidism was related to Sabbatianism was due to the fact that the Hasidim were threatening, and as the Jews who would become known as the Misnagdim didn't know much about Sabbatianism except that it was related to mysticism would have confused them and think that there is a causal link. However, just as the Vilna Gaon was a mixture between the concept 'Gaon' and 'Hasid,' so we should also think about the Besht. His beliefs were not the radical Hasidic ideas. The concept of the immanent God (that God is in everything) only reached its apex in the thought of Shneur Zalman of Łiady. The Besht, indeed, was a combination of the new Lurianic ideas but also the old concer of the mystical Baal Shem (a folk healer -- tied to popular religion and superstition). That is also a Kabbalistic idea, but tied to the "practical" Kabbalah of Abraham Abulafia (13th century).

The battle between the Hasidim and Misnagdim was only resolved after the death of the Vilna Gaon. In the early 19th century two things happened: first, the Russian government acknowledged the hAsidim, and the Hasidim's attempts to "conquer the communities" were highly successful. It really was not related to opposition to the Haskalah -- though the Misnagdim and Hasidim did come into an alliance against the Haskalah in the second half of the 19th century. The establishment of the great yeshiva of Hayyim of Volozhin (1802) created a new kind of environment where Hasidism and Misnagdism could meet. But apeven so there still remained a great religious divide between Misnagdism and Hasidism. Misnagdism essentially believed in a dualistic religious existence -- that this life is transitory to the next, and that we suffer here for the future world to come. Ultimately it was a very pessimistic view on the possibility of human salvation. The Hasidim, on the other hand, believed in a monistic world -- I.e. that one should enjoy the current life, and that salvation (devekuth or mystical union with god-- in medieval terms, unio mystica) is available to the average person.

Comment: For many people I know, Chasidus is still controversial.

Comment: @avi that still doesn't make it the right word to use.

Comment: why not?  In some places it will stop the conversation.

Comment: @avi It may *be* controversial. What I am saying is that it *was* not "controversial." There is a difference. It is the wrong word to describe the phenomenon of Hasidism, because "controversial" makes it seem like it was less significant than it was. When a politician makes a gaffe, that is controversial. Hasidism was a much bigger deal.