# Is it forbidden for a Jew to read the writings of Baruch Spinoza?

Tags: halacha, hashkafah-philosophy, books-generally, cherem

The cherem against Spinoza says the following:

> The Lords of the ma'amad, having long known of the evil opinions and acts of Baruch de Espinoza...  We order that no one should communicate with him orally or in writing, or show him any favor, or stay with him under the same roof, or within four ells of him, or read anything composed or written by him.

*Source: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baruch_Spinoza#Expulsion_from_the_Jewish_religious_community).*

Does this mean that Jews today are forbidden from reading his texts? Does the manner in which one might read Spinoza's texts matter, such as whether they were assigned in a class?

Comment: This is a community excommunication. This is not universally binding halacha.

Comment: similar http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/17590/759

Comment: @ShmuelBrin Except most of it isn't Kefira. The _cherem_ applied/s (apparently) to anything he wrote.

Comment: “You can learn anything so long as you have a competent Rabbi who can answer all your questions. And, if you don’t have a Rabbi, it’s even forbidden for you to learn Torah since it’s forbidden to learn Torah without a Rabbi.” - R’ Uri Sherqi (Makhon Me’ir)

Answer (score 3):

Someone asked this to Rav Meir Mazuz Shlita [here](http://www.ykr.org.il/modules/Ask/answer/10756):

> אשתי מורה ועושה תואר שני בתנ"ך במכללה דתית [מהזרם הציוני דתי]. במהלך אחד הקורסים, נתבקשו ע"י מרצה אחד, לקרוא מאמר של שפינוזה. וכן דברו שם על בקורת המקרא. כששאלה אשתי את המרצה [חובש הכיפה] שידוע שהרבנים אוסרים לשמוע דברים מסוג זה, אמר: איפה הרב עובדיה [שליט"א] פוסק שאסור?
>   האם אפשר לקבל מקורות לאיסור? [גם על קריאת בקורת המקרא, וגם התיחסות לשפינוזה ודעותיו].

To summarize, the man's wife was required to read Spinoza for college.

[Rav Mazouz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meir_Mazuz) responded:

> ספינוזה ידוע ככופר בעיקר ומומר, אין שום היתר לקרוא בספריו (לא שנו אלא באפיקורס נכרי, אבל באפיקורס ישראל כל שכן דפקר טפי. גמרא סנהדרין).
>   כל מבקרי המקרא אינם מאמינים בתורה מן השמים. ולכן ספריהם פסולים. רק מותר להביא דבריהם בהרצאה על מנת להפריך אותם.

To summarize: It is absolutely forbidden to read his works. The only exception would be mention of his views in a lecture in order to refute them (which would be permitted).

Thus, he holds that even as assigned reading it is forbidden.