# Do any various "orthodox" groups forbid marriage to other groups?

Tags: halacha, marriage, communities

Out of the various "Orthodox" groups, i.e. Litvish, Chassidim, Sephardim, Yemenites, etc., do any of them forbid marriage to the other?

Answer (score 1):

No there is no prohibition to marry between these different groups.

As long as they are from a kosher Jewish lineage (not offspring from a forbidden relationship, come from a Jewish mother etc.) there is no prohibition to marry them.

Regarding Chassidim, there was a ban issued by the Vilna Gaon against them which included a ban in marriage. However [this does not apply nowadays](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/17590/5514).

There are cultural and Halachic differences between them, which may lead to more marriages from "within".

I once heard from a great Rabbi that "marriage is hard as is, no need to make it harder by marrying someone from a totally different cultural backround"

Comment: when you say "Legitimate Orthodoxy" is that excluding any groups in particular, any of the groups I specifically mentioned?

Comment: Is there a prohibition on marrying non-orthodox Jews? I have never heard of such a prohibition.

Comment: I was only answering towards the groups cited above. Ie. They are kosher Jews thus no prohibition. If I have implied something else I can edit accordingly

Comment: You know this for a fact? Have you spoken to any Bobover's?

Comment: There's no prohibition. Machlokes and sinaah is not a prohibition

Comment: I have heard that there is often difficulty within the NYC Syrian community for those who wish to marry non-Syrians, due to the Edict, which is discussed elsewhere.

Comment: There is no edict to not marry Ashkenazim, not socially acceptable but not prohibited. Only converts are

Comment: I believe you have implied that there is a prohibition to marry people who are not part of a "subset of legitimate orthodoxy."

Comment: @mefaresh no, but I edited it. Please revert if you don't think the edit is within your intentions.