# Looking for info about the issur to marry chassidim

Tags: history, marriage, chasidut-hasidism, cherem, misnaged

In the early days of the "war" between the misnagdim and the chassidim, some of the leading Rabbis of the misnagdim made some sort of public cherem forbidding marriage to chassidim. Are there any public records in existence of this cherem? Is it followed by any groups of Jews?

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/17590/759

Comment: Didn't Rabbi Chaim Volozhiner remove the cherem at some point?